# Restrict wearable app to receive mobile app notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I am trying to develop a mobile & wearable app.

For this application, I want to add some action to the notification. `E.g., Delete & Reply`

Intent intent  = new Intent(MyActivity.this,MyActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity.this,0,intent,0);

```
            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity.this,0,nextIntent,1);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notifyCompat = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyActivity.this).addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Reply",pendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Delete",pendingIntent1)
                    .setContentText("Content Text")
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            Notification notification =notifyCompat.build();
            NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notifyManager.notify(0,notification);
```

That is what I did to show notification with action. But, my problem is, when I click on `Reply` or `Delete` in the notification of mobile, then its launching mobile app activity which is fine. But, if I click on `Delete` or `Reply` button on the notification on `Android Wear`, then it has to launch `Wearable Activity` instead of launching `Mobile App Activity`.

Can someone help me on how to achieve that? If I click on an action on `Android Wearable device` then it has to launch `Wearable App` but not mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to set up Wear-side Activities on a notification created on the handheld.

However, you can get the same effect with the following:

1. Make the handheld notification display only on the handheld with [NotificationCompat.Builder.setLocalOnly](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLocalOnly%28boolean%29)
2. When you create the handheld notification, also send a message to Wear using the [Messaging API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html)
3. In your Wear-side code, when you receive this type of message, create a notification (using the same notification API that you used in the handheld) - this will raise a notification on the Wear device
4. Any actions associated with the Wear-side notification will be launched on the Wear device